# Suppose $A,B\subseteq [0,1]$ are Lebesgue measurable with measure of at least $1/2$.

Tags: measure-theory

> Suppose $A,B\subseteq [0,1]$ are Lebesgue measurable with measure of at least $1/2$. Prove there is some $x\in [-1,1]$ such that $\mu((A+x)\cap B)\geq 1/10$.

[This is a previous qual question.](http://www.math.purdue.edu/files/academic/grad/qualexams/MA54400/MA54400_2015_JAN.pdf) My thought is to define the function $f(x)=\mu((A+x)\cap B)$. Then we know that $f(-1)=f(1)=0$, $f$ is continuous and $f$ is non-negative. I was thinking of applying IVT in some way but I can't see how.

Could someone provide a hint? (I would prefer hints only to a full answer)

Comment: Might be [helpful](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010192/convolution-of-characteristic-functions)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: compute the integral of $f$ on $[-1,1]$, and argue by contradiction.

Comment: Haha, I briefly thought about doing that. I couldn't think of what the integral would be, though. Could you offer a tiny bit more?

Comment: Are you familiar with convolutions? The function $f$ you defined is equal to $\chi_A*\chi_B$ (almost).

Comment: Then we can integrate that and use Fubini's to get that $\int f\ge 1/4$ but if $f<1/10$ then $\int f\le 1/5$. Contradiction. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Problems involving sets like $x+A$ always scream 'convolution' to me. I would try convolving $\chi_A$ and $\chi_B$. The resulting function $g= \chi_A * \chi_B$ is continuous, supported on $[-1,1]$ and integrates to at least $1/4$ (if my half-baked mental math is correct the integral can be easily computed with Fubini). How can we use this to get a lower bound for $g$ (and thus for $f$ as you have defined)? Here I use $\chi_A$ to denote the indicator function of $A$.

Comment: Thank you! I can only accept one answer. Sorry I couldn't accept yours as well! +1

Comment: I'm just glad to help. Good luck with your qual!