# Showing $\chi_A \ast \chi_B(x)$ is continuous if $m(A),m(B) \in (0,\infty)$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lp-spaces

Let $A,B \subset \Bbb{R}$ be Borel measurable with $m(A),m(B) \in (0,\infty)$, then prove $\chi_A \ast \chi_B$ is continuous.

**Attempt:**

Note

$$f(x)=\chi_A \ast \chi_B (x)=\int \chi_A(x-y)\chi_B(y)dy.$$

As $C_c(\Bbb{R}) \subset L^1(\Bbb{R})$ is dense, there exists $g_n \in C_c(\Bbb{R}$) such that

$$\Vert g_n - \chi_A \Vert_1 \to 0.$$
Then for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$, one has
$$
\begin{align}
\vert g_n \ast \chi_B(x) - \chi_A \ast \chi_B(x) \vert&\leq\int \chi_B(x-y)\vert g_n(y)-\chi_A(y) \vert dy\\
&\leq \Vert g_n - \chi_A \Vert_1\to 0.
\end{align}
$$
Thus $g_n \ast \chi_B \to \chi_A \ast \chi_B$ thus it suffices to show $g_n \ast \chi_B$ is continuous. As $g_n$ is uniformly continuous, for all $\epsilon >0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $\vert x - y \vert<\delta$, then $\vert g_n(x) - g_n(y) \vert<\epsilon$. So for $x_1,x_2$ such that $\vert x_1 - x_2 \vert<\delta$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\vert g_n \ast \chi_B (x_1) - g_n \ast \chi_B(x_2) \vert&\leq \int \vert g_n(x_1-y)-g_n(x_2-y) \vert \chi_B(y)dy\\
&\leq \epsilon m(B).
\end{align}
$$
as $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, one has $g_n \ast \chi_B$ is uniformly continuous thus $\chi_A \ast \chi_B$ is the uniform limit of continuous functions and thus continuous.

Does this proof work? Can someone, anyone help me out?! Also why would someone vote to close this it’s perfectly valid!!

Comment: Yes, argument based on approximation by elements of $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ is the "usual" route. Since your argument involves multiple kinds of convergence, it might help to be slightly more explicit at times, e.g. where you write "Thus $g_n * \chi_B \to  \chi_A * \chi_B$" without qualification it might be better to write "Thus $g_n * \chi_B \to \chi_A * \chi_B$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$."
See also the accepted answer to [convolution of characteristic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010192/convolution-of-characteristic-functions), using the same idea for a more general result.

Comment: Awesome !  thanks so much! So my argument works then ? @leslietownes ? And yes you’re correct I should be more specific!